# How To Prevent Appending An Object Changing Cycles Material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, append

I'm new to Cycles.

I have an object in one file with a material set:

[image]

When I append this object into another file, the material changes:

[image]

How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: You appear to have disabled (or significantly changed) color management in the first file. The actual material settings appear to be the same.

Comment: Thank you! The first file was saved from a version of blender that was a few (3+) years old. It must have been causing the issue. I imported the models/materials into a new file, saved over the old file, and I can now append with no problem. Thank you!